# couchdb query a view with key parameters

Tags: json, couchdb

Without a key parameter, the view works correctly

`$curl "http://127.0.0.1:5984/music/_design/albums/_view/by_release_date"`

```
{"total_rows":311,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"a4327d0718d3b1e227df7124a99a7fc3","key":"1991-12-22","value":{"by":"张楚","title":"黑月亮"}},
{"id":"a4327d0718d3b1e227df7124a99a3ac5","key":"unknown","value":{"by":"郑钧","title":"郑钧:赤裸裸"}},
```

but when with a key, i got either bad request response or empty result. Why?

`$curl  "http://127.0.0.1:5984/music/_design/albums/_view/by_release_date?key=unknown"`
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}

`$curl  "http://127.0.0.1:5984/music/_design/albums/_view/by_release_date?key=1993"`
{"total_rows":311,"offset":0,"rows":[

]}

The map function is:

```
map
function(doc) {
  key = doc.release_date
  value = {by: doc.author , title: doc.title}
  emit(key, value);
}
```

Answer (score 36):

The key is a string hence you need to include `"` = `%22`, e.g `http://127.0.0.1:5984/music/_design/albums/_view/by_release_date?key=%221993%22`

Comment: Thank you Daniel, it works. However, it is weird for me. even did not quote, couchdb should be able to get the parameters as a string. right?

Comment: Nope. It needs to be JSON compatible http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API

Comment: If it is working and you are pleased with the answer, feel free to mark as such ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to query key range. Try to specify `startkey` and `endkey`:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/music/_design/albums/_view/by_release_date?startkey=1993&endkey=1993z
```

More details: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how i deal with it**

```
let serverURL = "SERVER_IP:5984"
let dd_name = 'email' // for example
let viewname = "by_email" // for example

const findDocByEmail = email => {
  let url = `${serverURL}/_design/${dd_name}/_view/${viewname}?key="${email}"`
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: "no-cors",
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('COUCH_USER:SECRET'), // you can remove this if not needed,
    }
  })
  .then(res => {
    return res.json()
  })
  .then(response => console.log('Response: ', response))
  .catch(error =>  console.log(error))

}
```