# How to query CouchDB with non id field?

Tags: curl, couchdb, couchdb-1.6

I have a following document

```
{
   "_id": "00094248b3a7a744a88b2c77b1001c5d",
    type: 'contact',
    firstname: 'firstname',
    lastname: 'lastname',
    email: ['home': 'foobar@foobar.net', 'work': 'foobar@foobar-working.net'],
    phone: ['home': '+81 00 0000 0000'],
    address: [],
    files: [
        name : "SomeNAME",
        id : "SOMEID"
    ]

}
```

Now I want to retrieve the document with files{id}=SOMEID, How do I achieve that using curl?

Note that I'm using CouchDB 1.6, so the Mongo style queries are not available to me.

Answer (score 0):

First define a [view](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html). Ad hoc queries is something couchdb in general doesn't do.
You can find an example, complete with map function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887268/couchdb-query-a-view-with-key-parameters).